# ViewChild returns undefined while returning from child component to parent component

Tags: angular, typescript, daterangepicker, viewchild

I declared a `ViewChild` object of `DateRangePickerComponent`. **Last 7 Days** is the default selected date range. but I Updated it to **Last 30 Days** in a function `updateDateRange()` whiche is call within `ngAfterViewInit()` life cycle hook. But when I navigate to a child component and navigate back to parent component I called the `updateDateRange()` function to update **Date Range** from default **Last 7 Days** to **Last 30 Days**. But the object of `DateRangePickerComponent` becomes `undefined` as view does not initiated rather view changed.

In summary

**First of All I am in the parent page. At present when the parent page initiates its view I Declared an object of DateRangePickerComponent. And Changes the selected date range using my custom updateDateRange() function. Till now its works fine. But when I navigate to a child component and come back to the the parent, then the object of DateRangePickerComponent which was created before becomes undefined. that's the scenario.**

So how can I resolve this. Code is given below.

**Parent html file**
`

```
<div>
   **main block of code**
   
   **injecting Child component**
   <app-child-component (directiveBack)="navigatePage(pageSwitch.ViewPage, $event)"></app-child-component>
   
</div>
```

**Parent ts file**
`

```
parent class{
    @ViewChild(DateRangePickerComponent) private permissionDateRange: DateRangePickerComponent;
    searchFilter: ExampleInputDto;
    
    constructor(injector: Injector){
        super(injector);
        this.searchFilter = new ExampleInputDto();
        this.searchFilter.fromDate = moment().subtract(30, 'days');
        this.searchFilter.toDate = this.appConst.calenderSettings.daterangePickerOptions.toDate; //appConsts holds the constant files used in application.
    }

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        updateDateRange();
    }

    updateDateRange(): void {
        this.permissionDateRange.datePicker.setStartDate(this.searchFilter.fromDate.toDate());
        this.permissionDateRange.datePicker.setEndDate(this.searchFilter.toDate.toDate());
    }

    navigatePage(switchEnum: SwitchEnums, data?: any): void {
        if (data) {
            this.searchFilter.fromDate = moment().subtract(30, 'days');
            this.searchFilter.toDate = this.appConst.calenderSettings.daterangePickerOptions.toDate;
            this.updateDateRange();
        }
    }
}
```

`

**Child ts file**

`

```
  child class{
      @Output() directiveBack: EventEmitter<>;

      constructor(){}

      navigateBack(): void {             //this function is called after clicking back button in child html
          this.directiveBack.emit(null)
      }
  }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I would try using static ViewChild:

```
 @ViewChild(DateRangePickerComponent, { static: true }) private permissionDateRange: DateRangePickerComponent;
    searchFilter: ExampleInputDto;
```

> With static queries (static: true), the query resolves once the view
> has been created, but before change detection runs. The result,
> though, will never be updated to reflect changes to your view, such as
> changes to ngIf and ngFor blocks.

Moover you can change `ngAfterViewInit` to `ngOnInit` in this approach.

Comment: I tried with static query(static: true) before. it can not use for `DateRnagePickerComponent`

Comment: I would try to put that options via component Inputs instead of ViewChild.

Or try with another datePicker, this one 
 is very popular [link](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)

Comment: I hope Input instead of `ViewChild ` can not resolve this issue. May be I Could not clear the scenario. First of All I am in the parent page. At present when the parent page initiates its view I Declared an object of `DateRangePickerComponent`.  And Changes the selected date range using my custom `updateDateRange()` function. Till now its works fine. But when I navigate to a child component and come back to the the parent, then the object of `DateRangePickerComponent` which was created before becomes undefined. that's the scenario.